# Efficient many to two relationship

Tags: database-design, architecture

I'm building out a database with a `users` table, and I want to store the mutual (Facebook) friends between every set of two users in the database. Doing this in a normalized, efficient way seems tricky. I've considered two options so far:

***Option 1***

Create a table mutual_friend_set with columns `id, user1_id, user2_id`. Create another table mutual_friends with columns `id, mutual_friend_set_id, name, picture, unique_mutual_friend_id`.

The problem with this solution is that there's nothing to distinguish `user1_id` from `user2_id`, so I'd need to either create duplicate entries such as:

```
id   user1_id  user2_id
1    123       456
1    456       123
```

which would take up twice as many rows as necessary and throw normalization out the window, or ensure the lower of the 2 user_ids was in the user1_id column. If, however, I wanted to get all mutual friend sets for a single user, I'd need to query across both columns.

***Option 2***

Create a table `mutual_friend_set` with fields `id, user_pair`, such that user pair is a string of the combined user relationship, delimited by a comma. Eg: `id: 1, user_pair: '123,456'`. The user with the lower ID would be placed before the comma.

This would get around the normalization issues, but of course if I wanted to grab all the mutual friends pairs for a single user I'd have to run a `LIKE` query which isn't exactly efficient.

I assume this is a common problem, which raises the question: is there a standard way of doing this? Given my inexperience, am I missing something obvious?

Any ideas appreciated

Comment: Distinguish them arithmetically by `user1_id < user2_id`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? In Postgres you could store the pairs as an array which can be searched highly efficiently (faster than using `LIKE`). A graph database is another option to consider

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using postgres, and an arrary field sounds like it might be ideal. Many thanks for the thought, will investigate

Comment: @Kondybas Thanks for the thought, however with that approach I'd need to search both columns if/when I wanted to find all rows for a specific user.

Comment: @PlankTon So what with the search? Anyway you need a complex unique index for (user1_id, user2_id) therefore you are always able to use `WHERE user1_id = _some_id OR  user2_id = _some_id`

Answer (score 0):

`Adding as friend` is not a commutative operation. When A add B as friend that doesn't means that B do the same for A. That is why the mutuality emerge.

You definitely need both rows:

```
id   user1_id  user2_idz
1    123       456
2    456       123
```

If you want to get mutual relationships from that table, you have to `JOIN` it with itself:

```
SELECT w.*
  FROM friends AS w
  JOIN friends AS z ON z.user2_id = w.user1_id
                   AND z.user1_id = w.user2_id
                   AND w.user1_id < w.user2_id
```